# ML - Getting feature names after feature selection - SelectPercentile, python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have been struggling with this one for a while.
My goal is to take a text feature that I have, and find the best 5-10 words in it to help me classify. Hence, I am running a TfIdfVectorizer, and choosing ~90 best for now. however, after I downsize the feature amount, I am unable to see which features were actually chosen.

here is what I have:

```
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif

train=pandas.read_csv("train.tsv", sep='\t')
labels_train = train["label"]
documents = []

for i, row in train.iterrows():
    documents.append((row['boilerplate'][1:-1].lower()))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, stop_words="english")
features_train_transformed = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

selector = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile=0.1)
selector.fit(features_train_transformed, labels_train)
features_train_transformed = selector.transform(features_train_transformed).toarray()
```

The result is that features_train_transformed contains a matrix of all the tfidf scores per word per document of the selected words, however I have no idea which words were chosen, and methods like "get_feature_names()" are unavailable for the class SelectPercentile.

This is neccesary because i need to add these features to a bunch of numeric features and only then make my training and predictions.

Answer (score 1):

- selector.get_support() to get you a boolean array of columns that were within the percentile range you specified
- train.columns.values should get you the complete list of column names for the original dataframe
- filtering the latter with the former should give you the names of columns that make up your chosen percentile range.

the code below (cut-pasted from working code) is similar enough to yours, that it's hopefully helpful

```
import numpy as np
selection = SelectPercentile(f_regression, percentile=2)
train_minus_target = train.drop("y", axis=1)
x_features = selection.fit_transform(train_minus_target, y_train)
columns = np.asarray(train_minus_target.columns.values)
support = np.asarray(selection.get_support())
columns_with_support = columns[support]
```

Reference:
[about get_support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.get_support)